# Metadata extractor java doesn't extract exif or iptc

Tags: java, metadata, exif, iptc, metadata-extractor

I am trying to get the exif of a jpeg image but it doesn't work. First I read my image using BufferedImage and I convert it to a file and then I apply the same code as here: https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/browse/Samples/com/drew/metadata/SampleUsage.java?name=2.5.1. What am I doing wrong? Why does the JpegSegmentReader.SEGMENT_APP1 returns null?

```
    File outfile = new File("image.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(imagine, "jpg", outfile);
    try{
            JpegSegmentReader segmentReader = new JpegSegmentReader(outfile);
            byte[] exifSegment = segmentReader.readSegment(JpegSegmentReader.SEGMENT_APP1);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(segmentReader.readSegment(JpegSegmentReader.SEGMENT_APP1)));
            byte[] iptcSegment = segmentReader.readSegment(JpegSegmentReader.SEGMENT_APPD);
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            if (exifSegment != null)
                new ExifReader().extract(new ByteArrayReader(exifSegment), metadata);
            if (iptcSegment != null)
                new IptcReader().extract(new ByteArrayReader(iptcSegment), metadata);
            printImageTags(metadata);
        }catch (JpegProcessingException e) {
            System.err.println("error 3a: " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIO.write()` doesn't write Exif metadata* (APP1/Exif). It only stores JFIF (for more information on Exif/JFIF, see [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) on WikiPedia) in the APP0 segment. Because of this, there will never be an APP1 segment in your code.

There's also no Exif metadata available in the `BufferedImage` or `RenderedImage` that you are writing, as objects of these types only contain pixel data.

If you want to extract Exif metadata, you need to find a reference to the original file you read the image (`imagine`) from, and read from there.

*) `ImageIO` and the standard `JPEGImageWriter` *can* write Exif metadata, but only if you pass the Exif metadata to the writer, using the `IIOMetadata` API. But I don't think this is relevant for your use case.